# Common Lisp Programmatic Keyword

Tags: common-lisp

Is there a function in Common Lisp that takes a string as an argument and returns a keyword?

Example: `(keyword "foo")` -> `:foo`

Comment: alexandria has a make-keyword function

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here's a `make-keyword` function which packages up keyword creation process (`intern`ing of a name into the `KEYWORD` package). :-)

```
(defun make-keyword (name) (values (intern name "KEYWORD")))
```

Comment: Almost, but not quite. When you create a keyword, you must also ensure that you set its value binding to itself.

Comment: @Vatine I only have SBCL to test, and in SBCL, `(symbol-value (intern "FOO" "KEYWORD"))` already has the correct value. Besides, Alexandria implements it using the same approach also.

Comment: @Vatine [11.1.2.3.1 Interning a Symbol in the KEYWORD Package](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/11_abca.htm) says (emphasis added), *"The KEYWORD package is treated differently than other packages in that special actions are taken when a symbol is interned in it. In particular, when a symbol is interned in the KEYWORD package, it is automatically made to be an external symbol and **is automatically made to be a constant variable with itself as a value.**"*

Answer (score 44):

The answers given while being roughly correct do not produce a correct solution to the question's example.

Consider:

```
CL-USER(4): (intern "foo" :keyword)

:|foo|
NIL
CL-USER(5): (eq * :foo)

NIL
```

Usually you want to apply STRING-UPCASE to the string before interning it, thus:

```
(defun make-keyword (name) (values (intern (string-upcase name) "KEYWORD")))
```

Comment: It could be, of course, that OP just had print-case set to `:downcase`…

Answer (score 3):

There is a `make-keyword` function in the [Alexandria](http://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/) library, although it does preserve case so to get exactly what you want you'll have to upcase the string first.

Comment: Or set `print-case` to `:downcase`.  `intern` doesn't do any case modification, so the solution here probably shouldn't either.  (Although the example in the question does say `(keyword "foo") => :foo`, it's probably better to have `(... "foo") => :|foo|` or `(... "FOO") => :FOO`.)

Answer (score 2):

In case, you can change the string to start with colon sign `:`

use `read-from-string` directly.

Here is another version of `make-keyword`:

```
(defun make-keyword (name)
           (read-from-string (concatenate 'string ":" name)))
```

Comment: Can't you just do `(read-from-string (concatenate 'string ":" name))`?

Answer (score 1):

In this example it also deals with strings with spaces (replacing them by dots):

```
(defun make-keyword (name) (values (intern (substitute #\. #\space (string-upcase name)) :keyword)))
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you'd want to replace spaces with dots?  If you intern `"foo bar"` you get a symbol with the name `"foo bar"`, and there's no problem with that.  `intern` doesn't replace spaces with dots, either.

Answer (score -5):

```
(intern "foo" "KEYWORD") -> :foo
```

See the [Strings section](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/strings.html#converting-between-symbols-and-strings) of the [Common Lisp Cookbook](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/) for other string/symbol conversions and a detailed discussion of symbols and packages.

Comment: The name needs to be interned in the "KEYWORD" package to be a keyword. e.g., (intern "FOO" "KEYWORD")

Comment: ah yes. The (intern "foo" "KEYWORD") works quite nicely. Thank you.

Comment: In my answer, I've packaged it up into a neat little function, which you may enjoy. :-)