# Creating a keyword symbol

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, symbols

I'm trying to create a macro that takes some keyword parameters and, only if the parameter is defined, add entries to a list. Splitting this up the following code should illustrate what I need.

```
(defun add-if-not-null (var lst)
  (if (not (null var))
      (append (cons (***) (cons ver '())) lst)))
```

The three asterisks show the part I'm trying to figure out. This basically takes a symbol name and turns it into a keyword representation. e.g. width converts to :width

```
(let ((width 100))
    (add-if-not-null (width '())))
```

Should return

```
(:width 100)
```

I'm using cl-who to create an svg representation and basically want to set attributes like width and height only if they are specified as parameters to my macro that wraps the document.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Common Lisp Programmatic Keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211717/common-lisp-programmatic-keyword) (noting that you can get the string `"WIDTH"` from the symbol `width` by `(symbol-name 'width)`).

Comment: Also see [How does one create a keyword symbol from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24066178/1281433)

Comment: Neither of these fit the bill as I mention below. I need to find a way to turn a variable/parameter name into keyword parameter. If I need to convert it to a string along the way that's fine. If you look at the example then the answers thus far would not produce a correct solution.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  I attached too closely to "This basically takes a symbol name and turns it into a keyword representation."  The thing is, there's no symbol `width` in the compiled code.  There's a lexical variable that in the *source* is represented by the symbol `width`.  You'll need a macro to make this work, but the good news is that it's not too hard.  I think Rainer's edit gets it right for you.

Comment: Absolutely right @Joshua Taylor. I mis-spoke and need to be clearer with my questions. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of the package is `KEYWORD`. Symbols are created (if necessary) and put into a package using `INTERN`.

```
CL-USER 11 > (intern (symbol-name 'width) "KEYWORD")
:WIDTH
```

A macro:

```
CL-USER 29 > (defmacro add-if-not-null (var list)
               (check-type var symbol)
               `(when var
                  (push (list ,(intern (symbol-name var) "KEYWORD") var)
                        ,list)))
ADD-IF-NOT-NULL

CL-USER 30 > (macroexpand-1 '(add-if-not-null width some-list))
(WHEN VAR (PUSH (LIST :WIDTH VAR) SOME-LIST))
T
```

Comment: That's almost what I need but the problem lies in the (symbol-name 'width) call. Width is a function parameter so I need to replace that with something that converts a variable name to a string instead. E.g. I need (some-function width) that returns the string "width" another invocation would be (some-function any-variable) returns "any-variable". I have a suspicion I'm making this harder than it needs to be but I'm coming back to lisp after a long hiatus.

Comment: @Sprucial: see my edit. Sorry, I wanted to add it earlier, but got distracted. Here it is, though. Maybe that's what you need?

Comment: Thanks @Rainer Joswig. This is almost exactly what I needed. Here is what I actually ended up with ```(defmacro add-if-not-null-macro (var lst)
 `(if ,var 
      (append ,lst (list (intern (symbol-name (quote ,var)) "KEYWORD") ,var)) 
      ,lst))
```

Comment: @Sprucial: note that you can write `list` in Common Lisp. No need to write `lst`. Also: you are appending to the end of a list. Which is a bad way to use singly-linked lists.